# How to edit CSS so button appears on same line as input field?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

This is an issue inside a shopping cart, so unfortunately it's a multi-step process to view it:

1. https://blendbee.com/shop/black-tea-blends/happy-times/
2. Click one of the 3 "Add to cart" buttons
3. Click "View Cart"
4. Notice that the "Apply Gift card" button appears on a lower line.  **I'd like it to be to the right of the "Gift Cart" input field.**

[image]

Thanks in advance guys! You rock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
    <div id="entry">
        <form>
            <input id="input" placeholder="Coupon Code"></input>
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Apply Coupon</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    display: inline;
    width: 70%;
}
button {
    display: inline;
    width: 20%;
}
```

The width makes it so that they two will never "overflow" the width of the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have inline styling as such:

```
<input name="giftcard_code" class="input-text" id="giftcard_code" style="line-height: 1em; padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 6px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 4px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border-top-color: #e0dadf; border-right-color: #e0dadf; border-bottom-color: #e0dadf; border-left-color: #e0dadf; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; float: left; outline-width: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-color: invert; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);" type="text" placeholder="Gift Card" value=""/>
```

Insert:

```
width:100px; display:inline;
```

Anywhere inside the style attribute like this:

```
<input name="giftcard_code" class="input-text" id="giftcard_code" style="width:100px; display:inline; line-height: 1em; padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 6px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 4px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border-top-color: #e0dadf; border-right-color: #e0dadf; border-bottom-color: #e0dadf; border-left-color: #e0dadf; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; float: left; outline-width: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-color: invert; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);" type="text" placeholder="Gift Card" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (CSS):

```
#giftcard_code {width: 300px;}
```

Feel free to change the "width" to anything :) With so many floats in place, you have to specify dimensions to elements, since browser thinks 100% width in these cases.